# Getting Error in running Cmd command in from javascript code

Tags: javascript, cmd, ls

I am trying to run cmd commands throung my javascript code. Here's my code

```
var process = require('child_process');
process.exec('ipconfig',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
```

and when I run ipconfig it runs and shows all ip configuartions but when I run ls to show files on my directory it gives me error

```
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Can you run `ls` in a console window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows console, `ls` is not a command. Try using `dir` instead.